# Is there a word for the act of clearing one's throat?

Tags: single-word-requests

A lot of people, especially those with a throat infection, make an oft irritating guttural noise to clear their throat. What is the act called?

Comment: It's called *clearing your throat*.

Comment: In swedish, we have a single word for it (`harkla`), but when translating that it only gives `clears his throat` ([Translate](https://translate.google.se/#sv/en/harklar)). I don't think there is a word with the same description and a single word but still covering all cases.

Comment: What's up with 'hawk' as the unmarked word? 'hock' is all I've ever known. Does everyone here have the cot-caught merger? or is it just an eggcorn?

Comment: @Mitch *Hawk* is the original word; your *hock* is an alteration, cot-caught merger or not.

Answer (score 8):

Historically, *hawk* (also *hock*) meant to clear the throat in the general sense. Now it refers to gathering phlegm for spitting, by a progressive closing of the tongue against the back of the throat, accompanied by an outrush of air, a rising pitch, and vocalisation.

*Retch* also meant to clear the throat or cough up, from the Old English verb *hræcan*, to cough up or spit phlegm (*hraca*). Now it refers to the sound and motion of vomiting, either gagging or dry-heaving, often with a falling guttural sound.

So while we have had two good strong English one-syllable verbs to express what you mean, they’ve both drifted into new roles. In the present, I think *ahem* is the best verb we’ve got:

> My coworker Bill is just getting over a throat infection and was ahemming all day. Better than last week, when he would hawk loogies into his handkerchief.

Comment: This seems to be a repeat answer.

Comment: @Tom: But it has more information and makes a different recommendation.

Comment: If you have the exact same answer as someone else, the point of stack is to improve their answer.  However I have to read through yours to find out that I have already read that answer (actually answers since you took two words).

Comment: @Tom Editing the other post to include Jon's additional information would be far too radical of a change. Just because two answers include some information in common doesn't mean they're duplicates.

Comment: @Tom Please also see [Etiquette for simultaneous duplicate answers](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3847/etiquette-for-simultaneous-duplicate-answers) on Meta. Usual ELU practice for cases like this is to allow similar answers to stand on their own merits, and critical comments interfere with that. Please flag a moderator instead if you think two answers are too similar.

Comment: "Gunk" eh. Stop copying me! Stop it!

Answer (score 6):

If you are clearing your throat to draw attention I would use **ahem (hem)**.  If you are clearing your throat to get rid of mucus I would use **hawk**.

You would hawk a loogie.  And if you had no manners you would *say*, "ahem" to get everyone's attention before hand.

Comment: *Ahem* is essentially an interjection/ exclamation. To verbify that may be acceptable but not desirable. *Hawk* is mere onomatopoeia as is *ahem*.

Comment: @Kris: *Mere* is too dismissive. Onomatopoeia may not be so formal, but it is evocative!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a little 19th-century, but I do like *to harrumph*. It's the sound of clearing one's throat, although not necessarily to gather mucus.

[harrumph](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/harrumph)

Answer (score -1):

what about "hork" or "horking" which means clearing your throat, too?

Comment: Please provide some evidence for the use of this word.

Comment: I think you mean *hawking* , which might not be a bad answer if you provided some support.