# Throat sounds: is there a name?

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

Is there a word to describe the sounds we make in our throats? We ‘hmm’ or ‘mmmph’ involuntarily based on our emotions. The sounds are different based on our mother tongue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a word for the act of clearing one's throat?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130319/is-there-a-word-for-the-act-of-clearing-ones-throat)

Answer (score 0):

The idiom **hem and haw** meaning *to hesitate or to be indecisive* comes from the onomatopoeic words **hem** and **haw**.

*Collins* defines the words thus:

**hem**

> a representation of the sound of clearing the throat, used to gain attention, express hesitation, etc.

**haw**

> an inarticulate utterance, as of hesitation, embarrassment, etc; hem.